# Applying VS2015DarkTheme issue on dockpanelsuite 2.14.0

Tags: dockpanel-suite

I'm using the **DockPanel Suite** by Weifen Luo **2.14.0** version.
When I apply the **VS2015DarkTheme** the arrow color for the overflow menu item renders black on gray background, when the arrow should be blue on mouserhover and a sort of white when not selected.

I see that in vs2015dark.vstheme.gz the color is well defined, but not apply.

```
  <Color Name="CommandBarMenuMouseOverSubmenuGlyph">
    <Background Type="CT_RAW" Source="FF007ACC" />
  </Color>
```

I see too the same issue in 2.12.0 version and unknow if this is the only color not applying.

[**Now it looks like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVzwK.png)

**Q: Can I patch this in my app or is some to fix ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: It can be categorized as part of this issue, https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/415 WinForms builtin renderor does not give us enough room to customize every colors. Thus, to achieve 100% matching a lot of work would be required. If you like to patch it, do it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lex Li

Well, I patch the **VisualStudioToolStripRenderer.cs** as follow, considering that I only use **VS2015DarkTheme**.

I add this after **OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)** definition:

```
    protected override void OnRenderArrow(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripArrowRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Pressed)
        {
            e.ArrowColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 122, 204);
        }
        else if (e.Item.Selected)
        {
            e.ArrowColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 122, 204);
        }
        else
        {
            e.ArrowColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 153, 153, 153);
        }

        base.OnRenderArrow(e);
    }
```

[**And Now looks like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZrin.png)